# Error while passing data through service in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I have created a class called Service.ts in order to pass data from one component to another in angular 8:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  myMethod$: Observable<any>;
  private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

   constructor() {
      this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();      
 }

myMethod(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
    this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

here is the "sender" component:

```
 user: User = new User();

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private myService: MyService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

getCliente(){

    //do stuff
    this.myService.myMethod(this.user);
  }
```

and here is the receiver component:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private myService: MyService) {
  this.myService.myMethod$.subscribe((data) => {
console.log("C",data);

});
}
```

the problem is that the log("C", data) does not work when i load the receiver component but only when I reload the sender component.

Here is my routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'sender', component: MainComponent },
{ path: 'receiver', component: PrimoPianoComponent }


 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `BehaviorSubject` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) that will keep the most recent value around for the next subscriber to get as the first value in its stream.